# Booting from USB in UEFI

Tags: usb, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 in Dualboot with WIndows 8 on my UEFI System. After that there was no boot option for the USB in the System Setup anymore, which was there before under the title 'Uefi 8.0x'.
How can I now boot from my USB?

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions, none of which is guaranteed to work:

- Try checking your firmware options; several may be relevant:

  - There may be one to enable/disable booting from USB devices.
  - There may also be options related to USB initialization. Some settings will cause the computer to skip USB initialization altogether or to do "quick" initialization.
  - "Fast boot" options may cause the system to skip or do "quick" USB initialization, so disable any such setting you find.
- Try unplugging your USB boot device, reboot, plug the device back in, and reboot again.
- Try installing my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) There's a chance that it will present a boot option that your built-in boot manager doesn't. (Note that you'll need to uncomment and adjust the `scanfor` line if you want to boot BIOS-mode USB flash drives.) Also, check back in the future, because I'm working on improving the legacy boot options, which might cause rEFInd to detect such devices more reliably. The code isn't ready for release just yet, though. If you install rEFInd via its Debian package or by running the `install.sh` script, it will become your default boot manager. If you want to keep using GRUB for that, you'll need to do a manual installation (skipping the use of `efibootmgr`) and then adjust your GRUB configuration to provide an option to launch rEFInd.
- Try mounting a USB device that has an EFI boot mode and then using `efibootmgr` to add an entry to the `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` file on that device. (Read the `efibootmgr` man page or see [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html#register) for information on using `efibootmgr`.) Note that the entry you create will work only for the EFI-bootable medium you've just registered (it won't work for another USB flash drive), and some EFIs might erase it if you boot with the flash drive unplugged.